# The length of a side when two sides are given and a relation for angles are given in a triangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

The answer is $97$. How do you solve this? I've tried the sine rule.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\frac{\sin x}{125} =\frac{\sin 3x}{195} = \frac{3\sin x -4\sin^3 x}{195}  \\ \implies \sin x=\frac 35$$ Again using the sine rule, $$\frac{\sin C}{c} =\frac{\sin(180-4x)}{c} =\frac{\sin x}{125} =\frac{3}{625} \\ c=\frac{625}{3} \sin 4x$$ To find $\sin 4x$, note that $$\sin 4x =2\sin(2x) \cos(2x) =4\sin x\cos x \cdot (1-2\sin^2 x)=4\cdot \frac 35 \cdot \sqrt{1-\frac{9}{25}} \cdot \left(1-2\cdot \frac{9}{25}\right) =\frac{336}{625}$$ and so $$c-15=\frac{625}{3} \cdot \frac{336}{625}-15=97 $$

Answer (score 1):

Well, when we have a $\triangle\text{ABC}$:

[image]

We know that:

$$
\begin{cases}
\angle\alpha+\angle\beta+\angle\gamma=\pi\\
\\
\frac{\text{a}}{\sin\left(\angle\alpha\right)}=\frac{\text{b}}{\sin\left(\angle\beta\right)}=\frac{\text{c}}{\sin\left(\angle\gamma\right)}\\
\\
\text{a}^2=\text{b}^2+\text{c}^2-2\text{b}\text{c}\cos\left(\angle\alpha\right)\\
\\
\text{b}^2=\text{a}^2+\text{c}^2-2\text{a}\text{c}\cos\left(\angle\beta\right)\\
\\
\text{c}^2=\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2-2\text{a}\text{b}\cos\left(\angle\gamma\right)
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

In your case, we know $\text{a}=125$, $\text{b}=195$, $\angle\alpha=x^\circ$, and $\angle\beta=3x^\circ$, so:

$$
\begin{cases}
x^\circ+3x^\circ+\angle\gamma=180^\circ\\
\\
\frac{125}{\sin\left(x^\circ\right)}=\frac{195}{\sin\left(3x^\circ\right)}=\frac{\text{c}}{\sin\left(\angle\gamma\right)}\\
\\
125^2=195^2+\text{c}^2-2\cdot195\cdot\text{c}\cos\left(x^\circ\right)\\
\\
195^2=125^2+\text{c}^2-2\cdot125\cdot\text{c}\cos\left(3x^\circ\right)\\
\\
\text{c}^2=125^2+195^2-2\cdot125\cdot195\cos\left(\angle\gamma\right)
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

So, we know that:

$$x^\circ+3x^\circ+\angle\gamma=180^\circ\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\angle\gamma=180^\circ-4x^\circ\tag3$$

Comment: Well I know these formula's. Substitution and solving is going to be pretty difficult.Is there no easy method? We are supposed to solve this in 3 minutes or less

Comment: @STORMCR If you know these formulas, you must be able to figure out a fast way to solve it when you've the things that are given in the question. Think for a bit, I know you can do it.

Comment: Now I see that there is no shortcut,and that you have to do the whole ,Thanks guys

Comment: @STORMCR You're welcome!